# search in another application

Tags: android

I want to know can ı search youtube or another application on my application.

```
String s=" hi ";

 Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + s));
        startActivity(intent);
```

I can search using this code for youtube web site but I want to search in youtube android application (com.google.android.youtube ) . I will use below code for voice search .

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {  

                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                mVoiceInputTv.setText(result.get(0));
                String text =mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString();

                String filename = text;     // full file name
                String[] parts = filename.split("\\ "); // String array, each element is text between spaces
                String beforeFirstSpace = parts[0];    // Text before the first space

                if(beforeFirstSpace.equalsIgnoreCase("Youtube")) {   
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube"));
                   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
                   intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY,text);
                    startActivity(intent);

                   finish(); System.exit(0);
}
```

With this code I open the youtube application but I can't search in application.

Comment: What's other than youtube?

Comment: Create an `Intent Chooser`. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#AppChooser

Comment: Supporting an `http` URL with a query string is fairly unusual. Just because YouTube offers this does not mean that any other app does.

Comment: I just want to search in youtube application not web site                           Intent intent = new Intent(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube"));    
       
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
          intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY,s);     but it doesnt work

Comment: example for other app ; facebook , chrome , messenger ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it easily since other apps may (and most likely) offer another API that is different than youtube.

For example:

youtube search API:
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=facebook

facebook search API:
http://www.facebook.com/search/web/direct_search.php?q=%gmail

gmail search API:
Gmail: http://mail.google.com/mail/?search=query&view=tl&start=0&init=1&fs=1&q=%youtube

You see there is a different pattern. Thus, you need to implement it manually, 1 by 1, and according to the search API offered by every single app.